# MvvmCross 5.4.2 ShowViewModel with Presentation bundle Custom View presenter not called

Tags: xamarin.android, navigation, mvvmcross

I'm attempting a managed migration from MvvmCross v4.3.2 to V5.4.2. So at this point I am still using `ShowViewModel` to perform navigation.

I use a custom view presenter to enable things like taking a view out of the hierarchy when nvaigating.

When using v4.2.3 the custom view presenter was derived from `MvxFragmentsPresenter`, in my v5.4.2 version it derives from `MvxAppCompatViewPresenter`. however I have found that if I call `ShowViewModel` and pass a presentation `MvxBundle`, the overridden `ChangePresentation` method in my custom view presenter is not called.

This worked in v4.2.3. Is this a bug in v5.4.2 or is this a deliberate change to stop developers using ShowViewModel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken it used to call the overridden `ShowFragment`, not `ChangePresentation`. All working as should